# Access Rect class from Native

Tags: android-ndk

I'm trying to use NDK.
Suppose I have this java snippet to call a native function:

```
private native void changerect(Rect);

Rect r=new Rect();

r.set(10,10,100,100);

changerect(Rect r);
```

Then, the native function:

```
void changerect(JNIEnv *env, jobect this, jobject r)
{
 jclass rectClass=(*env)->GetObjectClass(env,r);
 jfieldID jid=(*env)->GetFieldID(env,rectClass,"left","I");
 jint l=(*env)->GetIntField(env,rectClass,fid);
 //now, change the left value
 l+=20;
 (*env)->SetIntField(env,rectClass,fid,l);
}
```

This compiles ok, but then I get an exception saying that the field left isn't part of the class?

Help, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass Rect object ('r' in your case) to the Get/SetIntField functions, i.e.

```
jint l=(*env)->GetIntField(env,r,fid);
(*env)->SetIntField(env,r,fid,l);
```